# Django 1.5 url template tag in if statement

Tags: django-templates

I am using url template tag as:

```
{% url 'profile_get_channel' selectedFeed.id c.id %}
```

witin my template i need a way to check if selectedFeed is not none. I have used

```
{% if selectedFeed %}
 {% url 'profile_get_channel' selectedFeed.id c.id %}
{% else %}
 {% url 'profile_get_all_channel' %}
{% endif %}
```

But if there is no selectedFeed i get

```
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'profile_get_channel' with arguments '('', '')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

How can i accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that the `selectedFeed` is not a "falsy" value (e.g. it's an object or similar) but the `selectedFeed.id` is empty/undefined. Try using:

```
{% if selectedFeed and selectedFeed.id %}
```

... so it will only use the "profile_get_channel" url if the id is defined.